# Can someone using a Detect Magic spell see a Subtle Spell being cast?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, sorcerer, metamagic

Can someone who has a *[detect magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic)* spell up see someone (for example, a Sorcerer) casting a spell that has the Subtle Spell metamagic applied to it?

Specifically, would the detector see the school of magic of the spell being cast from the example sorcerer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Nothing in the description of Subtle Spell indicates any change to how spellcasting interacts with *detect magic*.

Subtle Spell states:

> When you cast a spell, you can spend 1 sorcery point to cast it without any somatic or verbal components.

Since *detect magic* has nothing to do with spell components used, and Subtle Spell is only about spell components, Subtle Spell changes nothing about the function of *detect magic*.

So we don't care if the spell is cast with Subtle Spell, which means the question we're looking for is "how does *detect magic* detect a spell in the process of being cast?" *Detect magic* states:

> For the duration, you sense the presence of magic within 30 feet of you. If you sense magic in this way, you can use your action to see a faint aura around any visible creature or object in the area that bears magic, and you learn its school of magic, if any.

So you would probably sense that a spell is being cast, but you cannot learn  the school unless you use your action to do so.

Comment: Is the casting of a spell itself magical, or just any effects produced by the spell?

Answer (score 9):

### This is covered in Xanathar's

*Please note: the rules in Xanathar's are considered optional, but they are WotC approved.*

Under DM Tools [Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#PerceivingaCasteratWork):

> ... But what about the act of casting a spell? **Is it possible for someone to perceive that a spell is being cast in their presence?** To be perceptible, the casting of a spell must involve a verbal, somatic, or material component. The form of a material component doesn’t matter for the purposes of perception, whether it’s an object specified in the spell’s description, a component pouch, or a spellcasting focus.
> If the need for a spell’s components has been removed by a special ability, **such as the sorcerer’s Subtle Spell** feature or the Innate Spellcasting trait possessed by many creatures, the casting of the spell is imperceptible. If an imperceptible casting produces a perceptible effect, it’s normally impossible to determine who cast the spell in the absence of other evidence.

So if the spell only has a somatic and/or verbal component, and the caster uses Subtle Spell to remove it, then it cannot be detected. But if there is a material component, then it can still be detected.

The next section, [Identifying a spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#IdentifyingaSpell) says:

> ... Sometimes a character wants to identify a spell that someone else is casting...
> ... To do so, a character can use their reaction to identify a spell as it’s being cast...
> ... If the character perceived the casting, the spell’s effect, or both, the character can make an Intelligence (Arcana) check with the reaction or action. The DC equals 15 + the spell’s level. If the spell is cast as a class spell and the character is a member of that class, the check is made with advantage.
> ... This Intelligence (Arcana) check represents the fact that identifying a spell requires a quick mind and familiarity with the theory and practice of casting.

So, if we assume:

- The character already has the *detect magic* spell up
- The caster uses the Subtle Spell metamagic to remove the somatic/verbal components
- The spell being cast still has a material component that has not been removed

#### If the character has a reaction available at the time of casting

They can use their reaction and an Arcana (Intelligence) check to see if they can identify the exact spell.

#### If the character wishes to use their Action **after** the spell has been cast

The character can use *detect magic*'s feature to know the school of spell being cast.

#### If the spell has all required components removed, then there is no way to detect the spell is being cast

---

Since it's been brought up:

There is a difference between the act of casting a spell and a spell that has been cast. The act of casting a spell, is, in itself, not **magic**. At least not that can be detected via *detect magic*. It's just a person waving their hands, making funny noises, and/or playing with bat guano. Once the act is complete, then there is magic to be detected.

Note the wording in *detect magic*:

> For the duration, you sense **the presence of magic** within 30 feet of you. If you sense magic in this way, you can use your action to see a faint aura around any visible creature or object in the area **that bears magic**, and you learn its school of magic, if any.

The magic must already exist ("the presence of magic", "bears magic") in order for the spell to detect it. It cannot detect impending magic, like a spell about to be cast.

For examples of that, look at the [dispel magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) and [counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) spells.

In *counterspell* it says, "You attempt to **interrupt** a creature in the process of casting a spell." So this spell only works prior to a spell being cast. You're not removing magic, you're stopping a process. But *dispel magic* states, "Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range." It only works after there is already a magical effect. These are both third level spells so it's not a case of one spell being more powerful--one works before the magic and one works after the magic.

So there is no presence of magic, nor a creature that bears magic, until after the caster's spell is complete. That's why I phrased things above like I did.

---

As a DM, I would allow some interplay between those two options.

If the character uses their reaction to examine the spell as it is cast, then they still roll the Arcana check. On a success they know the spell (and can figure out the school), and on a fail they can only learn the school.

If the character uses their Action after the spell is cast, they can do the same Arcana check (success they know the spell, failure, they only learn the school).

Comment: *The act of casting a spell, is, in itself, not magic.* - That's what this all hinges on, but that's not a rule.  That's a decision for the DM about how magic works (narratively) in their campaign.  Counterspell's rules wording is equally compatible with a narrative where casting a spell is the process of spinning together some magical energies, and counterspell disrupts that.  The fact that a spell slot is used up even if counterspelled interrupts it is certainly compatible with there being detectable magic during cast. (But also compatible with not, or not for any observable time.)

Comment: The "identifying a spell" rules certainly look like they're written for characters who don't currently have Detect Magic active, leaving that as a special case interaction that a DM needs to rule on.

Comment: @PeterCordes, the rules don't need to cover it. The description of _detect magic_ clearly states the character must use **an Action** to see the aura and learn the school. They cannot use their Action on the turn someone else is casting a spell. The closest you could get is Readying an Action, so as a Reaction, they could learn the spell. So if they plan ahead, and use up their Action and Reaction, it can be possible. But it's not an automatic.

Comment: Detection (of magic without knowing the school) is an always-on part of Detect Magic: *For the duration, you sense the presence of magic within 30 feet of you. **If** you sense magic in this way, you can use your action ...* (to ID the school).  So you'd see that new magic appeared, but depending on the narrative details of Detect Magic (DM's choice) you might not know if it was a spell vs. a magical ability like Wildshape or Channel Divinity, or activating a magic item like winged boots.  (Again, assuming that there was magic to sense before they finished casting a spell).

Comment: Or if that sense of magic being present within 30ft of you is non-localized, and you need to use your action to get any kind of indication at all of where, then yes agreed it would be useless.  (Especially if anyone in the area had any magic item, or was using any magic ability which is pretty likely in most combats.  If you don't even get any sense of new magic coming online beyond the existing amount, that makes Detect Magic pretty weak for walking around to detect unexpected magic, unless you use your action every turn and look for auras.)

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, it is possible to detect a Subtle Spell being cast with *detect magic*

Detect Magic states:

> For the duration, **you sense the presence of magic** within 30 feet of you. If you sense magic in this way, you can use **your action** to see a faint aura **around any visible creature or object in the area that bears magic**, and you learn its school of magic, if any.

The *Sage Advice Compendium* states as one of the rules if something is magical:

> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?

Spellcasting (in most cases) is fueled by the use of spell slots, so such spellcasting as a process is magical, and can be detected with detect magic. Hence, you can detect the process of casting.

You sense the *presence of magic*, so you should be able to sense the casting of the spell, although you would not know if it is a spell or what school it is, just that there is some magic.

#### Can you find out the school?

You then would need **your action** for determining the school. Unless the spell was a spell with a long casting time, this would mean that you need to Ready an Action for using your action in response to the someone in question casting the spell.

Readying an action requires you to (PHB p. 193)

> decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction

and while casting a Subtle spell may normally have no "perceivable circumstance" as it involves no gestures or words, you can *sense magic*, and thus percieve something.

Normally "bearing" the magic of the spell means an enchanted object or creature, the act of casting a spell is not "bearing" a spell. The PHB however says on page 205:

> Whenever a magic effect is created, the threads of the Weave intertwine, twist, and fold to make the effect possible. When characters use divination spells such as **detect magic** or identify, they glimpse the Weave

Casting any spell is creating a magic effect, and this passage explictly says you can use *detect magic* to glimpse the Weave, so you should be able to see the effect casting a spell creates, even if the effect is instantaneous and does not leave a lingering effect like a concentration, permanent or limited duration spell would.

#### Csn you identify the caster?

This subject is also covered in *Xanathars Guide to Everything* (thanks to [MivaScott](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/201515)), which states:

> If an imperceptible casting produces a perceptible effect, it’s normally impossible to determine who cast the spell in the absence of other evidence.

Likewise here, it is probably impossible for you to know *who* did cast the Subtle Spell, all you can ascertain that it was cast, and of what school it was.

Comment: Since you are breaking this down to the "using your action to detect" level, you might want to add in the XGtE rules about detecting a spell as it is cast.

Comment: "Casting any spell is creating a magic effect" Things don't exist until they are created. In particular, they don't exist during the process of being created.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "When on my turn a spell begins to exist" is not well defined in 5e.  In general, it is difficult to parse anything finer than "the turn".  We do know that a Concentration spell ends _the moment_ you begin casting another Concentration spell.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel From the Basic Rules: "In casting a spell, a character carefully plucks at the invisible strands of raw magic suffusing the world, pins them in place in a particular pattern, sets them vibrating in a specific way, and then releases them to unleash the desired effect--in most cases, all in the span of seconds." Please compare "In casting a spell, a character... plucks... raw magic..., and then releases" with "you sense the presence of magic". The effect of the spell doesn't exist until the spell is cast, but the magic does.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel SAC has as one of the rules if something is magical the point "Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?", and spellcasting is not possible with spell slots, so spellcasting as a process is magical, and can be detected with detect magic.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin spellcasting is possible with (most spells) or without (cantrips) spell slots.

Comment: @JoelHarmon Before the question about spell slots, the second question SAC poses for determining if something is magic is "Is it a spell?" Safe to say, that covers cantrips as well.

Answer (score -1):

## It is plausible

Spells are magical, and the act of casting them is magical as it uses a spell slot.

Detect Magic detects things bearing magic, and it is reasonable that when casting a spell, you are bearing magic.

The rules are not 100% clear about it, so this is going to be something you'll want to discuss or clear up with your DM.  In my play experience, DMs are going to be pretty amenable to this -- I find most DMs will let Detect Magic stretch to things reasonably further than the explicit examples it lists.

However, details of the magic like "what school" explicitly require the Detect Magic user to expend their action.  Unless the spell that is being cast has a long casting time, or the detect magic user has readied an action to determine the school, expending an action when someone else is casting a spell is difficult.

So you'd see that the spellcaster is bearing magic.  Arguably this kind of magic bearing would be different than simply carrying a magical item, and would be noticed, and if you where skilled at magical theory (ie, Arcana trained) you could interpret it as "they might be casting a subtle spell".

You wouldn't likely get the school of the spell or anything else out of it however; definitely you aren't guaranteed to get it.

As a DM, I'd be willing to leak a hint, possibly gated behind an Arcana check.  Because that seems fun.  Not the school of magic (unless the check was really good), without requiring an reaction.  But don't like the Tasha's "identify spell being cast reaction" optional rule.

Comment: DM allows you to "sense the presence of magic", no bearing involved at that stage. That only comes in when using your action.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin: That's a DM choice for what that narratively means in their campaign.  The spell wording implies that you don't see auras at all without using your action, but the wording is compatible with learning general directions. And/or sensing that new magic has become active in the area, without necessarily knowing anything about where.  But if there's only one enemy, or one you know casts spells, and none of your allies would be using magic (e.g. a solo wizard with some mundane guards), that might be enough to be worth risking a counterspell when you sense new magic.

Comment: MivaScott and I [discussed this same point under their answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/201510/can-someone-using-a-detect-magic-spell-see-a-subtle-spell-being-cast/201515?noredirect=1#comment550295_201515).  Which left me wondering, if Detect Magic were that non-specific, wouldn't it always be detecting itself and never give you any information if you don't use your action?  That seems unintended, so a narrative interpretation that avoids that would be a good thing.

Comment: @PeterCordes That is a consequence I had not considered. I think that detect magics effect only happens after the spell has been successfully cast though, so you'd be done casting it by that time. It would shift the question to if the detecting you are then doing qualifies. I agree that ruling to say it does not is the only playable way.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin: I don't mean detecting yourself casting it, I mean detecting an active divination spell with duration: Concentration, up to 10 minutes.

Comment: Not all spells use spell slots. Cantrips don't, and some spells from eg.feats are use once per long rest without needing a slot per se.